# Moving objects automatically on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm wanting to create a webpage that moves an object in a specified pattern on the page.

For example, the user clicks a "Go" button and an object moves in a figure 8 pattern along the screen for 30 seconds.

I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me, I just can't seem to find anywhere to start - whether that's in CSS, JS or C#.

Comment: Since it is in client side (in browser) and a specific (not standard CSS animation) thing, you can't avoid usage of JS. If you need to calculate something also on server-side, here comes JS+C#.

Comment: The animation itself can actually be achieved with CSS, you'd only need JavaScript to initiate it.

Comment: Pure CSS example: http://codepen.io/ksksoft/pen/lsqEo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution one** -- Use CSS3's `@keyframes` and `animation`.

*Pro:* Very little coding.  You'll use the keyframes to specify `transform` or `transform3d` to specify exactly where you want an object to be at a given time, and it's off to the races.  CSS can take care of the timing and easing for you.  This can be as fine grained as you like, and without changing much you can also affect other things like scale, rotation, and opacity.

*For your specific use case, this is almost certainly what you will want to do.  Just remember that you'll be kicking off the animation via javascript.*

*Con:* It really is for pre-canned animation.  If you ever want the animation to follow the cursor, or stop mid-way through, this isn't what you want.

**Solution two** -- Use javascript to directly manipulate the `top` and `left` or the `transform` and `transform3d`.  You'll be doing this within a function set up by `requestAnimationFrame`.  At the end of that function, you'll call `requestionAnimationFrame` again.  Each time through the method, you'll update where the object is supposed to be at that time.

*Pros:* Fine grained control.  It can dynamically respond to events that are happening, and change its course mid-animation.  Written correctly, it can demonstrably be more performant than a CSS solution (although your scene may not be complex enough to notice this benefit).

*Cons:* With control comes responsibility.  It can be complex managing a scene, and it's probably overkill for making an object move in a figure 8 pattern.  But it does open up new vistas.

**Solution three** -- use a library that deals with this stuff for you.

If this is something we are going to do a lot, then there are some nice toolkits for complex animations -- [Greensock](http://greensock.com/get-started-js), for example.  I would definitely take a look at existing animation kits because they are going to really help make your code work across lots of different platforms.  They will also help with inevitable performance bottlenecks.

*Pro:* Let someone else manage the complexity of animation.  They've worked through the issues you might work through.

*Con:* Overkill is a funny thing.  Let your third party libraries exist to replace the tedium of doing it yourself, and not simply replace the lack of knowledge of how you might do it yourself.